# GridView row update and DropList

Tags: c#, .net

I have a `gridview` with column that have droplist when enter edit mode:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="genre" SortExpression="genre">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" 
                            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="name" DataValueField="name">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("genre") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

Now i want to take it to `UpdateParameters` of `SqlDataSource`:

```
    <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList2" Type="string" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Name="genre" />
    </UpdateParameters>
```

But when i pressed he give me Error msg

```
Could not find control 'DropDownList2' in ControlParameter 'genre'.
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Do you have any variable named `@genre` ?

Comment: The ID of `DropDownList2` might be changed, try using javascript alert to confirm: `var ddl = document.getElementById('DropDownList2'); alert(ddl);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DropDownList2 is a nested control located under the Grid; therefore, your SqlDataSource control does not have visibility at all of the DropDownList2.

You could try assigning the value on the code behind by using the Updating event:

```
protected void SqlDataSource_Updating(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
{
  e.Command.Parameters["@genre"].Value = GetDropDownListValue();
}
```

**Note:** You will need to use FindControl("DropDownList2") in GetDropDownListValue()